# Validate a block in hyperledger composer

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

---

I am kind of new to hyperledger, and am currently trying to set up a blockchain application with hyperledger composer. I have defined my models, scripts and acces control logic. What I didn't understand is how the transactions I send through API get added to the blockchain.

So I started digging in the Fabric documentation, to understand the logic allowing a transaction to go from a transaction to a new block appended to the blockchain. I believe I have reached the full comprehension of the transaction flow and the elements it involves. I have returned to the implementation of such a flow but have come to an unclear point about the tools I should use. If I understand well, Composer is a tool used to build blockchain applications over the Fabric framework. Fabric allows you to define rules and the way your network works, including its various components (peers, orderers, channels...)

The question is do I need to implement a blockchain network "from scratch" using Fabric before I can build my application using Composer, or is there a way to configure the transaction validation process (add/manage peers and endorsing peers, interact with the orderer...) and set channels directly on composer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Omar yes, you will have to implement a blockchain network "from scratch" using Fabric before you can build the application using Composer.

Not sure if you already had a chance to complete this course (recommended)

https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/ibm-blockchain-foundation-developer/

look at the flow diagram attached ( link here -> https://developer.ibm.com/code/patterns/build-a-blockchain-network/ )
[Workflow - Blockchain Newtwork using Composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JVR5.png)